# Shortest path linear programming

Tags: shortest-path, linear-programming

i am stuck at the point maximize d_t at page 4 https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs498dl1/sp2015/notes/26-lp.pdf.
I absolutely cannot follow the author argument

> These relaxation constraints imply that in any feasible solution, d_v
>   is atmost the shortest path distance from s to v .Thus, somewhat
>   counterintuitively,we are correctly maximizing the objective function
>   to compute the shortest path!

We are looking for the shortest path but why do we  loogking for max d_t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the trivial case of the shortest path between two directly connected vertices `s` and `t` without any other edges or vertices. Here the LP boils down to this:

```
maximize   d_t
subject to d_s = 0
           d_t − d_s ≤ l_st for every edge s -> t
```

The only way to maximize `d_t` is to set it to the shortest path from `s` to `t` - in this case the edge between the two. This is because the second constraint `d_t ≤ l_st` prohibits any larger value, i.e. any longer path from `s` to `t`.

Now, this idea can be transferred to the general case where `s` and `t` are not neighbouring vertices: Think of the `d` variables as shortest paths to all the neighbouring vertices of `t`. Then the contraints concerned with `d_t` determine which of these edges must be chosen to define the overall shortest path. It will be satisfied with equality while any higher value for `d_t` will violate at least one of these contraints.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm works like this: select `v` not in `S` with at least one edge `(u, v)` from `S`. Find `min d(u) + l(u, v)` and assign this to `d(v)`. Now suppose we have 3 nodes: `u`, `v` in `S` with `d(u) = 5` and `d(v) = 4` and `w` not in `S`. `l(u, w) = 1` and `l(v, w) = 3`. Constraint in the problem ensures that `d(v) <= 6` and if we're maximizing it will be exactly `6`.